# unlink in loop doesnt work

Tags: php, mysql

I ask for help with PHP code.
Simple unlink function works, but when it is in loop, it doesnt work. There has to be a problem somewhere. So heres the problem. I have a simple page where you can delete the navigation items. If user deletes navigation item (hes an administrator) and that link to page with some photos in it, I want to delete these photos when the user delete whole page. 
The PHP code:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM foto WHERE ID=".$inid;
    $vysledek = mysql_query($sql2) or die (mysql_error());
    while ($zaznam= MySQL_Fetch_Array($vysledek)) {
                $path = "maly/maly".$zaznam["url_v"];
                unlink($path);
                $path2 = "uploads/".$zaznam["url_v"];
                unlink($path2);     
            }
```

This code wont delete all matched photos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the statement

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM foto WHERE ID=".$inid;
```

Might be incorrect, perhaps

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM foto WHERE ID='".$inid."'";
```

(ignoring the fact of potential SQL injection).

But,

Why not echo the values of the current working directory along with `$path` and `$path2` to find out what is going wrong?

Otherwise it is difficult to tell.

BTW - mysql_* libraries are deprecated. Should move to summat like PDO or mysqli.

Comment: Suddenly it works! Thank you. Yeah I know that mysql_* lib are deprecated. Just dont know how to use the new ones. I am not that experienced programmer.

Comment: A tick or addition to my reputation would not go a miss.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand all that is being asked, but the path constructed does not seem correct.  It appears it should have a slash after `maly`:

```
$path = "maly/maly/".$zaznam["url_v"];
```

Comment: It because one of the picture is big and one is small - so small (in my language maly) is just connected to it.